# How to use quotes within quotes properly

Tags: javascript

If you create an HTML element with JS using a string like the following, how can you add the extra quotes required within an onclick event? Since I have already exhausted double and single quotes, is there an elegant way of making this work?

```
var foo_td="<td onclick='window.open('newpage.html', '_blank')'>Open Page</td>";
```

Comment: Read the documentation on string literals.

Comment: There is no better argument against constructing long sequences of JS as a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to replace innermost single quotes `'` with double quotes `"` and escape them with single backslash `\`, like this:

```
var foo_td="<td onclick='window.open(\"newpage.html\", \"_blank\")'>Open Page</td>";
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/94tzhjnu/)

**Why escape quotes at first place**

This is because when the `onclick` event will be fired on this `td` and if there are no quotes (if quotes not escaped), then it will look for a variable named `newpage.html` and `_blank` and give an error because these variables (most likely) won't exist.

**Why not only single backslash with single quote**

Single-backslash will only escape the string for the evaluation of this string expresion, and by the time this value is stored in a string it will ignore this backslash.

**Why not double backslash with single quote**

By the time nodes are rendered on DOM (can check this on Developer Tools of your browser), its attribute values are enclosed inside a double quote rather than a single quote. So, it will be rendered as this and hence give an error.

```
<div onclick="window.open(\" newpage.html\',="" \'_blank\')'="">Open Page</div>
```

So, based on three reasons given above you should **always escape double quote**  **if you want to pass a string parameter to a function call from an attribute**.

Comment: @dlofrodloh I have made the changes and included a demo link. Please check again

Comment: thanks for the solution and explanation, works perfect now!